# Span tag disappear after few seconds

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I have two `div` those contain `h` tag inside which I have a `span` tag those contain letters

First Div

```
<div class="startname">
  <h6 class="alphabets" >
          <span class="letters">A</span>
          <span class="letters">B</span>
          <span class="letters">C</span>
          <span class="letters">D</span>
          <span class="letters">E</span>
          <span class="letters">F</span>
    </h6>
</div>
```

Second Div

```
<div class="endname">
  <h6 class="alphabets" >
          <span class="letters">G</span>
          <span class="letters">H</span>
          <span class="letters">&nbsp;</span> 
          <span class="letters">I</span>
          <span class="letters">J</span>
    </h6>
</div>
```

> First div starts from left top of the screen and scales to a particular location using keyframe

> Second div starts from few pixels below the first div of the screen and scales to a particular location using keyframe

I want letters `EF` in `startname` and `<whitespace>IJ` in `lastname` to disappear after few seconds of `startname` and `lastname` align

Here's the [code](https://codepen.io/ssddayz/pen/zKZaBQ) I found which pages `div` disappear after few seconds

Tried it out in `svelte` doesn't seem to be working here's the entire code below. How do I achieve the desired result?

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(fadeout, 4000); //8 seconds
}
function fadeout() {
  document.getElementById('fadeout').style.opacity = '0';
}
</script>
<style>
  .startname {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: startnamemymove 5s 1 forwards;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:flex-end;

}
#fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 3s opacity;
}

.endname {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: endnamemymove 5s 1 forwards;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

@keyframes startnamemymove {
  from {top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  transform: scale(.5);}
  to {top:150px;left: 200px;
  transform: scale(2.0);
  }
}
@keyframes endnamemymove {
  from {top: 100px;
  left:100px;
  transform: scale(.5);}
  to {top:0px;left: 500px;
  transform: scale(2.0);
  }
}
</style>
<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<div class="startname">
  <h6 class="alphabets" >
          <span class="letters">A</span>
          <span class="letters">B</span>
          <span class="letters">C</span>
          <span class="letters">D</span>
          <span class="letters" id="fadeout">E</span>
          <span class="letters" id="fadeout">F</span>
</div>
<div class="endname">
  <h6 class="alphabets" >
          <span class="letters">G</span>
          <span class="letters">H</span>
          <span class="letters" id="fadeout">&nbsp;</span>      
          <span class="letters" id="fadeout">I</span>
          <span class="letters" id="fadeout">J</span>
          
    </h6>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with these modifications:

- set the transition class after a timeout via Svelte's [`use:action`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action)
  (the class has to have the `:global()` flag so it gets compiled even though the class is not directly used. And both classes are needed `:global(.letters.fadeout)` so that the specificity is enough to overwrite the setting of the first class, because these elements have the Svelte suffix added `.letters.svelte-5nw7mj`)
- get rid of the whitespace between `<span>` elements by setting `display:flex` on the `<h6>` ([a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements))
- if the width should be animated, it must be set before on the `<span>` elements. This can be done by giving them `display: inline-block;` and the desired width

->> a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ce8a5c31fdcd445cb14d635dad30db61?version=3.46.5)

(I reduced the time to 3s so it was faster to try out...)

```
<script>
    function handleFadeout(node) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            node.classList.add('fadeout')
        },3000)
    }
</script>

<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<div class="startname">
    <h6 class="alphabets" >
        <span class="letters">A</span>
        <span class="letters">B</span>
        <span class="letters">C</span>
        <span class="letters">D</span>
        <span class="letters" use:handleFadeout>E</span>
        <span class="letters" use:handleFadeout>F</span>
    </h6>
</div>
<div class="endname">
    <h6 class="alphabets" >
        <span class="letters">G</span>
        <span class="letters">H</span>
        <span class="letters" use:handleFadeout>&nbsp;</span>      
        <span class="letters" use:handleFadeout>I</span>
        <span class="letters" use:handleFadeout>J</span>
    </h6>
</div>

<style>
    .startname {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        animation: startnamemymove 3s 1 forwards;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content:flex-end;

    }

    .endname {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        animation: endnamemymove 3s 1 forwards;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    @keyframes startnamemymove {
        from {top: 0px;
            left:0px;
            transform: scale(.5);}
        to {top:150px;left: 200px;
            transform: scale(2.0);
        }
    }
    @keyframes endnamemymove {
        from {top: 100px;
            left:100px;
            transform: scale(.5);}
        to {top:0px;left: 500px;
            transform: scale(2.0);
        }
    }

    .letters {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 12px;
    }

    h6 {
        display:flex;
    }

    :global(.letters.fadeout) {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 300ms;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Looks more clean + `Svelte`

Comment: Similarly how to make `handleFadein` that makes character appear after few seconds. I was unable to replicate it

Comment: Not sure I understand - that's a new logic you would like to implement or what's the problem?

Comment: You mean [like this?](https://svelte.dev/repl/e00a1ec101e4433cb46fedd4b15724b7?version=3.46.5) Notice I moved the `transition: all 300ms;` to the `.letters` class (you could add a seperate function for handling the fade use:handleFadein and use:handleFadeout, but in this case i would combine both because they are related

Comment: Reading your comment again I think you want them to be invisible from the beginning and have them appear after the intro animation? This could be done [like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/9c245386a5ee4c4baccf51cbf45bd1bc?version=3.46.5) 1. add the class to the elements from the beginning 2. move transition prop in css to .letters 3. remove the class after the timeout (overall variable naming should be adjusted :-))

Comment: Yes `invisible` in beginning, then `visible` after few seconds, Your second comment was exactly the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use same id in several elements. Please use class.

Comment: `Class` has already been used, It has some other functionality in the main code. If not `id` what can be used? Overall solution?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31411253)

Comment: @fafl it does provide answer his code not works because he uses ids.

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth use another class

Answer (score 1):

The method `getElementById()` will return only the first element with that id. You can use classes and `getElementsByClassName()`, which returns the list of elements with that class name. Here is the [code](https://codepen.io/michele96/pen/JjMyKOa).

Answer (score 1):

The error is on repeating id fadeout more than once.

You need to create a new class with the styles you want and put it together with letters: `class="letters fadeout"`. Just a space between.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#id_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result which can help you.

Steps need to remember

- HTML attribute ID will be use on single element
- You can use `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()` to apply opacity in multiple elements.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(fadeout, 4000); //8 seconds
}
function fadeout() {
    document.querySelectorAll('span.fadeout').forEach(el => {
        el.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

```css
.startname {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: startnamemymove 5s 1 forwards;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    padding-right: 10px;
    

}
.fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 3s opacity;
}

.endname {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: endnamemymove 5s 1 forwards;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

@keyframes startnamemymove {
  from {top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  transform: scale(.5);}
  to {top:150px;left: 200px;
  transform: scale(2.0);
  }
}
@keyframes endnamemymove {
  from {top: 100px;
  left:100px;
  transform: scale(.5);}
  to {top:0px;left: 500px;
  transform: scale(2.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<div class="startname">
  <h6 class="alphabets" >
          <span class="letters">A</span>
          <span class="letters">B</span>
          <span class="letters">C</span>
          <span class="letters">D</span>
          <span class="letters fadeout">E</span>
          <span class="letters fadeout">F</span>
   </h6>
</div>
<div class="endname">
  <h6 class="alphabets" >
          <span class="letters">G</span>
          <span class="letters">H</span>
          <span class="letters fadeout">&nbsp;</span>      
          <span class="letters fadeout">I</span>
          <span class="letters fadeout">J</span>
    </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried out the code on the svelte terminal online [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/html-tags) altered as you have suggested but the letters don't seem to fade out

Comment: I was able achieve the same with only with `keyframe` without using `onload` but after the letters fade I want the `startname` and `endname` containers  till in the gap created when the letter disappears. How can I do it?

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth i have made some changes please check. Let me know if it is works fine for you or not.